# MySql update when multiple columns already eixsts otherwise insert new record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like the following

[image]

Basically I want to check if the combination of `(score_id, rater, rated)` already exists in the database, if it does, then I update the `score` field, otherwise I insert a new record into the DB.

I tried `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but it only works on the primary key. I'm looking for something similar but works on the values in other columns.

Comment: you need to create unique index on these three fields and then `insert ... on duplicate` will work

Comment: that will work as long as they are all not null.  if any value is null, that can have duplicate values even in the other two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by creating a unique key on those three columns with `alter table scores add unique key 'score_record' ('score_id', 'rater', 'rated');`